# Variable changes its value inside function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an RGB color guessing game.
It is working fine on the first run. On the second time using **New Game** button, new **pickedColor** and a set of random colors should be generated. Even though new **pickedColor** is generated every time (checked in *line 30*) but the value of **pickedColor** changes back to its previous value on *line 42*.

Why is it happening? How Can I get same value of **pickedColor** on *line 30* and *line 42*?

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var arr = [];
  var r = 0,
    g = 0,
    b = 0;
  var temp;

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    arr[i] = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  }

  return arr;
}

function pickColor(colors) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  return num;
}

function newGame() {
  var colors = getRandomColor();
  var colorTile = document.querySelectorAll(".colorTile");
  var pickedColor = colors[pickColor(colors)];
  console.log(pickedColor);
  console.log(colors);

  var rgbDisplay = document.querySelector("#rgbDisplay");
  var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

  rgbDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  for (var i = 0; i < colorTile.length; i++) {
    colorTile[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    colorTile[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(pickedColor);
      if (pickedColor === this.style.backgroundColor) {
        h1[1].textContent = "Correct";

        for (var j = 0; j < colorTile.length; j++) {
          colorTile[j].style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        }
      } else {
        h1[1].textContent = "Incorrect";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    });
  }
}

newGame();

var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
button[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
  h1[1].textContent = "Click On Tile"
  newGame();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.colorTile {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.6%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

HTML
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<link href="../css/ex160.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="../JavaScript/ex160.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Color Game</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>The Great <span id="rgbDisplay">RGB</span> Game</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
    <div class="colorTile"></div>
  </div>

  <h1>Click On Tile</h1>

  <button class="restart"><em>New Game</em></button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding multiple clicks on colorTile element with this line.

```
colorTile[i].addEventListener("click", function()
```

Try removeEventListener and then add new removeEventListener like this

```
function getRandomColor()
{
  var arr = [];
  var r=0, g=0, b=0;
  var temp;

  for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    arr[i] = "rgb("+r+", "+g+", "+b+")";
  }

  return arr;
}

function pickColor(colors)
{
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  return num;
}

var pickedColor = '';
var colorTile = document.querySelectorAll(".colorTile");
function newGame()
{
  var colors = getRandomColor();
  pickedColor = colors[pickColor(colors)];
  console.log(pickedColor);
  console.log(colors);

  var rgbDisplay = document.querySelector("#rgbDisplay");
  h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

  rgbDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  for(var i=0; i<colorTile.length; i++)
  {
    colorTile[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    colorTile[i].removeEventListener('click', fn)
    colorTile[i].addEventListener("click", fn);

  }

}
function fn (){
      console.log(pickedColor);
      if(pickedColor === this.style.backgroundColor)
      {
        h1[1].textContent = "Correct";

        for(var j=0; j<colorTile.length; j++)
        {
          colorTile[j].style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        }
      }

      else{
        h1[1].textContent = "Incorrect";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    }
newGame();

var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
button[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
  h1[1].textContent = "Click On Tile"
  newGame();
});
```

Comment: @Mihir, Please check updated code now. Although it has a major flaw that I have made pickedcolor and h1 as global and we should avoid any globals in js code.

Comment: Made pickedColor and colorTile global and code worked as expected. Can you please elaborate why pickedColor does not update due to multiple click ?

Comment: Update : I just define pickedColor globally in my code and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I played with your code and ended-up with a working snippet where I tried to enhance many things:

I tried to comment within the code during modifications.
With it, you can play with the amount of color tiles you want, and it's working nicely.

```js
// Define global variables all at the same place
var rgbDisplay = document.querySelector("#rgbDisplay");
var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
var tilesNumber = 6; // Select how much tiles you want to start with!
var pickedColor;
var button = document.querySelector("button");

// Added s to Colors in the name
// Removed "temp" variable and r g b initial values
function getRandomColors(nb) {
  var arr = [];
  var r, g, b;
  for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    arr[i] = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  }
  return arr;
}

// Removed variable used in this function
// Changed parameter to nb, that's the only thing used, no need to pass all the colors
function pickColor(nb) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * nb);
}

// Added nb as parameter of this function
function newGame(nb) {
  var colors = getRandomColors(nb); // Using nb
  pickedColor = colors[pickColor(nb)];
  rgbDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  container.innerHTML = ''; // Emptying container
  for (var i = 0; i < tilesNumber; i++) { // Adding new element for each tilesNumber
    var tile = document.createElement("div");
    tile.classList.add('colorTile');
    container.appendChild(tile);
    tile.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  }

  var colorTile = document.querySelectorAll(".colorTile");
  for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    colorTile[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (pickedColor === this.style.backgroundColor) {
        h1[1].textContent = "Correct";
        tilesNumber++; // We could add that funny kind of things, now!
        for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
          colorTile[j].style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        }
      } else {
        h1[1].textContent = "Incorrect";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    });
  }
}

// Event on button
// (Side question: Wouldn't be nice to disable it until correct answer?)
// Removed querySelection, because global variables…
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  h1[1].textContent = "Click On Tile";
  newGame(tilesNumber);
});

// Launch game
newGame(tilesNumber);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.colorTile {
  /* Modified */
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1.6%;
  padding: 0 0 30% 30%;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<link href="../css/ex160.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="../JavaScript/ex160.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Color Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The Great <span id="rgbDisplay">RGB</span> Game</h1>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <h1>Click On Tile</h1>
  <button class="restart"><em>New Game</em></button>
</body>

</html>
```

Feel free to comment if anything.

I hope it helps. :)